# Use polygon lines to create masks

Tags: qgis, vector, line, algorithm, masking

Given a tile (the cropped base map in the left) and polylines (red lines), is there any tool/workflow in QGIS to convert them into masks in the right?

[image]

Comment: With vector tools, you can extract the extent of the tile, you'll have a vector rectangle. Then you can "split with lines" (algorithm toolbox) the extent rectangle with your lines. The result will be a 4 part divided rectangle, as your right picture.

Comment: Thank you for the workflow. It works. I really appreciate you help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Even if it's located in Vector tools, you can extract the extent of your tile with this tool : ["Extract layer extent"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/layertools.html#extract-layer-extent). The result will be a rectangle (polygon) of the extent.
2. Split this rectangle extent with your line layer, using the ["Split with lines"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoroverlay.html#split-with-lines) processing tool. As its name, this tool will split your polygon layer (extent) with your line layer and divide it into different parts.